# How to hide ide main window title bar? (in IntelliJ IDEA)

Tags: intellij-idea

Title bar is completely useless for me. Info it shows i can see in navigation bar. [image: useless header]
It only takes space. Is it possible to hide the header as looks in Netbeans?

Answer (score 63):

1. install plugin: Window Decorate Mode Switcher
2. select view->switch decorate mode

You might want to toggle the "Auto undecorate on start" option under File > Settings > Switch Decorate Mode

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't work, I get "illegal component position".

Comment: Doesn't work ideally. When enabled phpstorm stays in a maximized state.

Comment: Worked for me with IntelliJ 2018.2 and Windows 7.

Comment: Works for me in PhpStorm 2019.1, but only with a fixed taskbar at the bottom. If you have your taskbar at the top or side of your screen, or in auto-hide mode, it doesn't work well.

Comment: Works for me in PyCharm 2020.3 on Linux.

Comment: Worked for me with Intellij Idea 2021.3 and Fedora 34.

Comment: This works for me in PhpStorm 2022.2 but unfortunately it introduces other issues that are more annoying than the menu bar, namely whitespace characters appear as bright white circles...

Comment: Great, this work for me with intellij IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.1 (Community Edition) and Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 23.04 with PHPStorm 2022.2.3

Answer (score 16):

If you use Windows 10 or Ubuntu (tested with IntelliJ Community 2019.2 on Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04; for Ubuntu: thanks to the comment of @demon101)

Hide (or show) native title bar on Windows

- Open Help -> Edit Custom Options...
- Allow a personal properties file to be created
- Add a line (true = hide; false = show)

```
ide.win.frame.decoration=true
```

- Restart IDEA

Comment: not work on Ubuntu 20.04 with IDEA 2020.02

Comment: Thank you it worked for me: Phpstorm 2018 and Windows 10. ♥

Comment: does not work with 2021.1 & Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: not work on Mac Monterey with Goland 2021.03.

Comment: It does not work in 22.04.1 LTS (2022.3.1 Ultimate.)

Answer (score 9):

I really do not know the way to hide this bar, but you could use 'Full Screen Mode'.

View -> Enter Full Screen

Comment: he, nice reply, but is there any way i can enter this mode on half a screen. I just want to hid the damm title bar. Ty.

Answer (score 7):

[Window Decorate Mode Switcher](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7698-window-decorate-mode-switcher) plugin works well for me on Gnome.

Comment: Worked like a charm on intellij 2020.2 and Ubuntu 20.04.1! Thanks :)

Comment: only works when maximized on intellij 2022.2.1 on Ubuntu 22.04.1

Answer (score 4):

This is the best solution I've found: the [No Title Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2015/no-title-bar-forked/) gnome extension.

Works for Linux only, but it works with ALL applications, not just those from JetBrains.

Very easy, just install the browser extension, refresh the page, click the switch to enable it, and then (optionally) remove the browser extension when you are done :) Takes effect immediately.

Answer (score 1):

For macOS, [Hide Title Bar](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/16244-hide-title-bar) plugin does the trick. It isn't perfect though, as traffic light buttons will slightly overlap the navigation bar.

It is also open source, in case anybody want to help improving it https://github.com/haringsrob/jetbrains-hide-title-bar

Answer (score 0):

This issue will be resolved in 2020.03, see [Option to disable merging main menu into window title](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219212)

Answer (score 0):

The title bar has been removed for the new UI in the version 2023.2.

see: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/?utm_source=product&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=IU&utm_content=2023.2

Answer (score -1):

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360004366159/comments/360000685899

Borderless UI can be disabled by the following steps:

1. press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+/
2. select Registry
3. switch off the ide.win.frame.decoraion key
4. restart IDE

Comment: @raman-sinyakov Didn't worked for me when I applied in Ubuntu 19.10 in IntelliJ Ultimate 2019.2.3