# Android Studio after update to 3.6 I see a black bar in the top of the windows in Windows 10

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

[image]Android Studio after update to 3.6 I see a black bar in the top of the windows in Windows 10.
How can I remove it? It is making mouse fails when trying to select items in menu.

Comment: post screenshots...

Comment: This might be a decoration from the Windows theme, because that area not belongs to the application window (don't have it with the default theme). Better save the icon from the 3.5 version, because that low-contrast mint icon is the main problem with 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this which seemed to be related [ide.win.frame.decoration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60874091/3351474) and it worked in my case.

I quote:

> Open Help -> Edit Custom Options...
>
> Allow a personal properties file to be created
>
> Add a line (true = hide; false = show)
>
> ide.win.frame.decoration=true
>
> Restart IDEA