# Can I revert Android Studio 3.6 update?

Tags: android, android-studio

Can I revert Android Studio 3.6 update?

I am using windows 10 and was using 3.5.

The current version is not allowing me to work.

Comment: You probably need to install it anew and disable auto-updates if you have them. You can get portable (zip) version and simply unpack it if you don't want to collide with your current installation. For whatever reason google is not exposing download links to old builds so you probably need to find it in website archieves.

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing? Working with newest version is a great thing and also challenging. Try to solve that problem.

Comment: i think you'd be better off asking a question related to a problem you're facing with android studio, instead of asking how you can revert it, seeing as though the update for 3.6 will always be there, you'll probably have to face this at some point..

Comment: I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60424798/android-studio-after-update-to-3-6-i-see-a-black-bar-in-the-top-of-the-windows-i